# silde div with importent image

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, responsive-design

i've got a div that slide by adding a class to it that changes his right value and it works fine, but there is an image inside this div and I need it to **responsively** always show the image

[image: this is when the div is closed]

now when it is closed i want to see only the picture(guess i need like a fixed image by the distance from the right side)

[image: this is the ideal result]

```
    .comingnext {
   transition-timing-function: ease;
   float: right;
   transition: right 2s;
   position: absolute;
   right:-70%;
   /**/height:20%;
   width:100%;
   top: 50%;
   z-index: 1000;

   padding: 5px;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   font-weight: bold;


}
.comingnext.out {
    right:-4%

}
```

my html:

```
<div ng-controller="toggleCtrl" class="comingnext" ng-class="class" ng-click="toggleClass()">
        <a class="nextthumb thumbnail-shadow item item-thumbnail-left card" href="#">

                          <img src="{{allTracks.NextTrack.ImgUrl}}">
                          <h2>Coming up next:</h2>
                          <h2>{{allTracks.NextTrack.Song}}</h2>
                          <p>{{allTracks.NextTrack.Artist}}</p>
                          <p>{{allTracks.NextTrack.Album}}</p>

                      </a>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the right image with a text, right?
So, just use media queries and put a `display:none` to your image text. Another solution might be using `position: relative`and `position: absolute` in his parent, and then change your image position as you please.
Hope this works.